# Applying @Provider annotation in Jersey conditionally or alternatives for @Provider annotation

Tags: spring, rest, annotations, jersey, provider

We have a Jersey-Spring project. We would like to use @Provider annotation conditionally. I.e. we want to use it only for certain environments. By enviroments I mean dev, staging, qa live etc.

We have used environment specific configuration in our projects using spring bean profiles. Is there anyway by which we can make sure that the @Provider is applied only when the environment is a particular one? (Note that in java code we know what the environment is.)

If the above is not possible, then is there anyway where we can avoid using the @provider annotation and use some kind of code which may do the job so that we can selectively apply it based on the environment.

```
@Provider
@Profile("docs")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
```

Basically we are using the @Provider to apply a JacksonJsonProvider but we want to apply this provider only in some environments.

Please let us know the best solution.
Thanking you.
-ND.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to put it in a separate package and only include that package in your required profiles.

Take a look at the PackagesResourceConfig, specifically the PROPERTY_PACKAGES.